# Analyzing the object position using C# generic list

Tags: c#, generic-list

I am computing the distance of an object.

The  X  and Y position values first stored in two different Lists X and W.

Then I use another List for storing the distance covered by this object.  Also, I refresh the lists if their count reaches 10, in order to avoid memory burden.

On the basis of distance value, I have to analyze, if the object is in the static position the distance should not increases. And on the text box display, the computed distance values appears to be static.

Actually, I am using sensors to compute the distance. And due to sensor error even if the object is in the static state the distance value varies. The sensor error threshold is about to be 15cm.

I have developed the logic, However, I receive error:

> `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index'

My code is as follows:

```
 void distance()
    {
        List<double> d = new List<double>();
        double sum = 0, sum1 = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < X.Count; i++)
        {           
          //distance computation

                if ((d[i] - d[i -1]) > 0.15)
                {
                sum1 = d.Sum();
                sum = sum1 + dis1;
                Dis = Math.Round(sum, 3);
                }
            }
          // refresh the Lists when X, W and d List reach the count of 10                
    }             
    }
```

Comment: What is `X` in your code? Another list?

Comment: What is `W` in your code? Another list?

Comment: yes X and W are another lists contains X and Y axis position values

Comment: the problem could be here `i - 1` but it is impossible to know from just this peace of code, check the size of both list and put a break point on the part a told

Comment: The problem is with d[i]. The first i is 1 when d is empty. And adding one element to d we can only access d[0] and not d[1]

Answer (score 1):

You do it totally wrong. Come up with a method computing a distance for a two given points. That's gonna be a func of signature `double -> double -> double` or, if you prefer C#, `double ComputeDistance(double startPoint, double endPoint)`.

Then the only thing to do is to apply such a fuction to each pair of points you got. The easiest and most compact way to accomplish that is by means of `Linq`. It could be done in a regular `foreach` as well.

Take a note that it would be a way clearer if you will eventually merge your separated lists into a single list. `Tuple<double, double>` seems to be the best choice including performance.